# Assigning methods inside class constructor

Tags: c#, methods, constructor

EDIT: Check the answer that I posted below. I created a proxy method that calls the other functions.

I have a class that I would like to assign methods from different classes. What's the best way to do so?

So far, I've tried this:

```
namespace LeagueProj.DataGrabber{
    public class DataGrabber : IDataGrabber
    {
        private SummonerMethod sm = new SummonerMethod();
        private MatchlistMethod mlm = new MatchlistMethod();
        private MatchMethod mm = new MatchMethod();

        public delegate Summoner GetSummoner();
        public delegate Matchlist GetMatchlist();
        public delegate Data GetAllMatchData();

        public DataGrabber()
        {
            GetSummoner = sm._GetSummoner;
            GetMatchlist = mlm._GetMatchlist;
            GetAllMatchData = mm._GetAllMatchData;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the IDE says that in the constructor, GetSummoner, GetMatchlist, and GetAllMatchData are types but are being used like a variable (which is understandable). I realize I probably am going about this wrong, so what's the best way to go about it?

Comment: [`delegate` creates a type, not a field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so a friend recommended to me that I just proxy the methods and have them return the other ones. That's a much better idea, imo. Here's the code for future reference:

```
namespace LeagueProj.DataGrabber
{
    public class DataGrabber
    {
        private SummonerMethod sm;
        private MatchlistMethod mlm = new MatchlistMethod();
        private MatchMethod mm = new MatchMethod();

        public Summoner GetSummoner(string summonerName) { return sm._GetSummoner(summonerName); }
        private List<Matchlist> GetMatchlist(long accountId) { return mlm._GetMatchlist(accountId); }
        public List<Data> GetAllMatchData(List<Matchlist> matchlist, long accountId) { return mm._GetAllMatchData(matchlist, accountId); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You declared delegate, but not a field with this type of delegate:

```
public class DataGrabber : IDataGrabber
{
    private SummonerMethod sm = new SummonerMethod();
    private MatchlistMethod mlm = new MatchlistMethod();
    private MatchMethod mm = new MatchMethod();

    public delegate Summoner GetSummoner();
    public delegate Matchlist GetMatchlist();
    public delegate Data GetAllMatchData();

    public GetSummoner Method1;
    public GetMatchlist Method2;
    public GetAllMatchData Method3;

    public DataGrabber()
    {
        Method1 = sm._GetSummoner;
        Method2 = mlm._GetMatchlist;
        Method3 = mm._GetAllMatchData;
    }
}
```

Comment: The first three lines of the class are probably still an error though, as I'm assuming that those are methods, not objects.

Comment: @RonBeyer Oh, I guess that would seem confusing haha, `new SummonerMethod` _does_ refer to a class. I suppose I should've made that clear.

Answer (score 1):

**You need to:**

- move the delegate outside class (not mandatory but generally the way it's done)
- add a constructor parameter of the type of the delegate
- assign the passed value in the constructor to a class-level variable

Example:

```
internal class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(GetElement getElement)
    {
        GetElement = getElement;
    }

    public GetElement GetElement { get; }
}

internal delegate Element GetElement();

internal class Element
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Action's:

```
public class MyActioner
{
    private Action MyAction;

    public MyActioner()
    {
        MyAction = () => MyActionMethod();
    }

    public void MyActionMethod() 
    {

    }
}
```